# Remote Connection Progam Like Teamviewer

Tags: tcp, tcpclient, remote-desktop, tcpserver

The Standard TCPServer and TCPClient don't work on my machine for some reason, but Teamviewer manages to make a connection between two machines, and I would guess that the actual remote desktop session isn't going through their servers as it would probably be quite heavy.

Could someone explain to be how this is possible, because I've tried every TCP server/client code I could find and it still cannot connect recieve information from the outside world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeamViewer uses a technique called [UDP Hole Punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching).

This allows to connect two nat'd peers without make data pass through a server.

Comment: This is very intersting and seems to be what i was looking for, but one more tiny question to finish it off, can this be done with a normal web server or does a dedicated server need to be setup?